# How to reuse fragment in dialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make fragment and use it in 2 different ways for tablets and smartphones:

tablet - fragment shows up as fragment dialog

smartphone - fragment shows up in separate activity.

I want to make class MyFragment and to use it both in activity (for smartphones) and in fragment dialogs (for tablets). Is that possible? If not, what I do wrong and how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

To show a simple edit dialog and return a result to the calling Activity using an interface. For design guidelines around Dialogs, [see the Android Design site](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html).

**The Layout**

Here’s the layout for the dialog in a file named fragment_edit_name.xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"  >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_your_name" android:text="Your name" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_your_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:inputType=”text”
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**The Dialog Code**

The dialog extends DialogFragment, and since we want backward compatibility, we’ll import it from the v4 support library. (To add the support library to an Eclipse project, right-click on the project and choose Android Tools | Add Support Library...).

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
// ...

public class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText mEditText;

    public EditNameDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
        getDialog().setTitle("Hello");

        return view;
    }
}
```

**Showing the Dialog**

Now we need some code in our Activity to show the dialog. Here is a simple example that immediately shows the EditNameDialog to enter the user’s name. On completion, it shows a Toast with the entered text.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
// ...

public class FragmentDialogDemo extends FragmentActivity implements EditNameDialogListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        showEditDialog();
    }

    private void showEditDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        EditNameDialog editNameDialog = new EditNameDialog();
        editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hi, " + inputText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Using the Dialog**

Next, let’s enhance EditNameDialog so it can return a result string to the Activity.

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
// ...
public class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener {

    public interface EditNameDialogListener {
        void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText);
    }

    private EditText mEditText;

    public EditNameDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
        getDialog().setTitle("Hello");

        // Show soft keyboard automatically
        mEditText.requestFocus();
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {
            // Return input text to activity
            EditNameDialogListener activity = (EditNameDialogListener) getActivity();
            activity.onFinishEditDialog(mEditText.getText().toString());
            this.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I meant how to make a fragment, which can be used both in dialog and in activity? I mean instances of the same fragment class to be inserted both into dialog and into activity.

Comment: i guess [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) here. :)